# Flask app running on gunicorn reload fails for templates & static files

Tags: python, kubernetes, flask, gunicorn, reload

This is my sample Python app structure. I have this app running under Kubernetes and have Procfile that detects and builds the app and deploys it. Reload works fine for Python files (.py) while static files like .html or .css files are not reloaded on change.

I can see the change files are copied into the container but Gunicorn doesn't restart the worker's thread when only static files are changed, while it restarts when copying the Python (.py) files. I have tried for a day now and am not sure where to look any help would help a ton.

```
.
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── Tiltfile
├── board
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── pages.py
│   ├── postgresql.py
│   ├── posts.py
│   ├── schema-postgres.sql
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
├── gunicorn_config.py
├── requirements.txt
├── venv
│   ├── bin
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   └── pyvenv.cfg
└── wsgi.py
```

gunicorn_config.py

```
workers = 1
loglevel = 'info'
reload = True
reload_extra_file = ['/workspace/board/templates/*.html', '/workspace/board/static/*.css']
errorlog = '-'
accesslog = '-'
threads = 2
worker_class = 'gthread'
```

wsgi.py

```
from board import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn -b :8080 wsgi:app --config gunicorn_config.py
```

All of the files are copied to `/workspace` folder in the container and as said above every change including the .html and .css change is reflected but the process doesn't reload/restart.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the wording. Gunicron doesn't restart on change to static files like .html and .css while it does for Python files ending .py.

Comment: You tagged this with [tag:kubernetes]; is this running in some sort of cluster environment?  I might expect to see a sequence of building a new container image using a tool like `docker build`, pushing it to a registry, updating `image:` references, and updating the Kubernetes Deployment object.  What does this deploy sequence look like?

Comment: Yes, it's running in Kubernetes. I use the Tanzu Application Platform to build and push code to production. By the way, I work for Tanzu so I'm biased here. You can do the same if you string together opensource tooling like Tiltdev for live update/debugging and Buildpacks for building your containers as you push code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, folks for all the help. I got it running. Typical I had a typo in the config its `reload_extra_files` and not `reload_extra_file`. Some of these values are different when used in the command line vs. in a python file.

gunicorn_config.py (working)

```
from glob import glob

workers = 1
loglevel = 'info'
reload = True
reload_extra_files = glob('board/**/*.html', recursive=True) + glob('board/**/*.css', recursive=True)
errorlog = '-'
accesslog = '-'
```